# Can not print link list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, printf

I'm very new to coding in C (and therefore the silly exercise I am working on).

I have a linked list, a function that is supposed to print my linked list, and main function.

Unfortunately my knowledge of C is not good enough to understand why this is not printing.  What is even more unfortunate is that this code does not crash.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} *Node_t;

void print_list(Node_t root) {
    while (root) {
        printf("%c ", root->data);
        root = root->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main () {
    int i;
    int n = 6;
    Node_t list = (Node_t)malloc(sizeof(struct Node) * n);
    Node_t root;

    for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
        list[i].data = i+1;
        if (i == n-1) {
            list[i].next = 0;
        }
        else {
            list[i].next = &list[i+1];
        }
    }

    root = &(list[0]);

    print_list(root);
}
```

Comment: never cast the result of malloc()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print_list` function has the wrong format specifier in `printf`. It should be

```
printf("%d ", root->data);
```

Corrected code:

```
void print_list(Node_t root) 
{
    while (root) {
        printf("%d ", root->data);
        root = root->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And no need to cast result of `malloc` - this should be fine:

```
 Node_t list = malloc(sizeof(struct Node) * n);
```

Answer (score 0):

printf("%d ", root->data); instead of  printf("%c ", root->data); because you are assigning integer data to list